# Rewrite sh script for freebsd

Tags: linux, bash, freebsd, sh

I have an sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
fullpath="$1"
filename="${fullpath##*/}"
dir="${fullpath:0:${#fullpath} - ${#filename}}" 
base="${filename%.[^.]*}"
ext="${filename:${#base} + 1}"   
if [ -f $fullpath ]; then
  if [ $ext != "mp4" ]; then
      ffmpeg -threads 4 -i $fullpath -y -vcodec libx264 -g 100 -bt 100k mp4 -vpre fast -acodec libfaac -ab 128k "$dir$base.mp4"
      mv -f "$dir$base.mp4" "/data/www/rfpl/htdocs/videotapes/$base.mp4"
  fi
fi
```

So, I wrote it for Linux, now I need to run it under FreeBSD, but I don't know anything about FreeBSD. There is an error:

> ./convert.sh: ${fullpath:0...}: Bad substitution.

I think that there is no bash, how can I make it to work?

Comment: Your script is running bash.  Is it an old version?  I'm wondering also if maybe you changed your script to run /bin/sh and forgot to indicate that in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have bash installed already, then the FreeBSD preferred way is to use the ports:

```
cd /usr/ports/shells/bash
make install clean
```

If you don't have the ports tree installed, you can install it by running:

```
portsnap fetch extract
```

Doing either of these things will need root privs.

Note also, that typically bash is installed in /usr/local/bin/bash
So you'll want to edit the first line of your script.
In fact check that bash isn't already installed, before trying the above.

Comment: This is a good answer, but the OPs script says it is already running bash.  So I wonder why he can't use standard bashisms?  Maybe he's running a really old bash?  Maybe the question is just missing some info.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to a freebsd box, but try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
fullpath="$1"
filename=$(basename $fullpath)
dir=$(dirname $fullpath)
ext=$(echo $filename | awk -F. '{ print $NF }')
base=$(echo $filename | sed "s/.${ext}//")
if [ -f $fullpath ]; then
  if [ $ext != "mp4" ]; then
    ffmpeg -threads 4 -i $fullpath -y -vcodec libx264 -g 100 -bt 100k mp4 -vpre fast -acodec libfaac -ab 128k "$dir/$base.mp4"
    mv -f "$dir/$base.mp4" "/data/www/rfpl/htdocs/videotapes/$base.mp4"
  fi
fi
```

Comment: I was just going to post something very similar - I checked the bsd man pages and dirname/basename are available.